# constructor function: where "public" properties located in memory on run-time

Tags: javascript, oop, memory-management, prototype

Let's create a simple constructor function:

```
function User(firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.sayHi = function () {
        console.log('Hi, my name is ' + this.firstName);
    };
}
```

It obvious that we can't write code like this:

```
console.log(User.firstName); //undefined
console.log(User.sayHi);     //undefined
```

Let's draw how User constructor function object located in memory on run-time:

```
 ______________
|              |
|    User      |
|______________|
|  prototype   |
|______________|
|     name     |
|______________|
|    length    |
|______________|
|  arguments   |
|______________|
```

So, we know that prototype, name, length and arguments properties are default for any function object. In fact, that there is no fields such firstName and sayHi in function object.

**So the question is:** 
Where in memory located properties "firstName" and "sayHi", until interpreter invoke code like this:

```
var user = new User('Bob');
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you would want to use setters and getters.   User.getfirstname() for example.  Trying to access private variables publicly is bad OOP.  Not just bad, but plain, wrong.

Comment: They don't exist until you add them to the object in the constructor.

Comment: The question is not about what's good or wrong in OOP. I'm talking about memory issues -- where on run-time interpreter locate public properties before he parse construction with "new" keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the question is: Where in memory located properties "firstName" and
>   "sayHi", until interpreter invoke code like this:
>
> var user = new User('Bob');

In your example, there are no properties `firstName` and `sayHi` UNTIL you create a new User object.  The constructor of your `User` object creates those properties on the object that is created by the `new` operator when it assigns them a value.  At that moment, those properties are created.

It's no different than if I have:

```
var x = {};
x.foo = "Hello";
```

The 'foo' property was automatically created when I assigned to it.  Before I assigned to it, the property did not exist.  Same in your object.

Now, if you had used the `.prototype` when defining your object, then it would have been a different story (the properties would have been defined in the prototype and automatically become part of the new object), but the way you defined your new object those properties did not exist before the object was created and the constructor code ran.

---

You could prove it to yourself with this code:

```
function User(firstName) {
    console.log(this.hasOwnProperty("firstName"));
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.sayHi = function () {
        console.log('Hi, my name is ' + this.firstName);
    };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/qfat6/

---

Here's the ultimate example of a dynamically created property that is not known ahead of time.

```
var obj = {};
var propName = window.prompt("Enter property Name");
if (propName) {
    var propValue = window.prompt("Enter property Value");
    if (propValue) {
        obj[propName] = propValue;
    }
}
```

If the user enters, "age" in the first prompt and "45" in the second prompt, then obj will have a property named `age` with a value of `"45"`.  That property did not exist before this code ran and could not have been known in advance.  It was simply created upon demand when the code ran that asked for it to be created.  Assigning to a non-existent property of an object in javascript just creates that property.

---

You've asked more questions about how/where code is stored.  I can explain just a little bit more on that topic, but the details or how things are stored in memory in javascript is entirely implementation specific.  It is not like C or C++ where an object has a very specific memory representation.  An interpreted language like Javascript does not have that.

When the code is initially parsed, a `Function` object is created for the User function.  That `Function` object then has a number of properties, which would include a reference to the code that goes with it.  How and where the Javascript engine stores that code is entirely up to the specific Javascript implementation and likely varies depending upon how the implementation chooses to manage memory.  It is not specified in a standard and there is no need for the code storage to be implemented the same in different implementations.  The only thing that must be true is that when that function is called that the interpreter knows how to retrieve the code for that Function object and execute it.

Comment: I think you don't understand my question. 
I’m talking about properties in memory, before we create an object with constructor function. 
1. Interpreter load js code in memory like a array of strings.
2. Then interpreter finds constructor function. 
3. Interpreter parses it and create a function object (empty one) 
But how he knows what fields should be create when we write code:
var user = new User();

You should understand that anyway interpreter knows what fields user object should contains. How interpreter understand what field it should be?

Comment: @YuryPetrankov - There simply are NO properties in your code until the constructor actually executes.  The interpreter doesn't know about those fields until the constructor executes and the interpreter encounters code that instructs it to create those properties.  In code like yours, Javascript adds those properties at runtime.  The ONLY thing that exists in memory before the constructor is executed is the string "firstName" as part of the code assignment function.   It's in the code, not in an object.

Comment: @YuryPetrankov - I think I did answer your exact question.  Those properties don't exist UNTIl the constructor is executed and then the interpreter encounters the code that creates the properties.  Javascript is unlike other languages like C++.  Javascript can just create properties dynamically at any time and they do not have to be defined ahead of time.

Comment: @YuryPetrankov - see the example I added to the end of my answer.

Comment: How js will know what properties it should add to the object? From your words js doesn't parse construction function body until it hasn't found new operator

Comment: @YuryPetrankov - Javascript only knows when you assign to a property and thus cause it to get created.  It doesn't know in advance of that or need to know in advance of that.  It is different than traditional compiled languages like "C" that want to know all of that in advance at compile time.  To correct one other thing in your last comment, javascript code is parsed when loaded (to put it in a more efficient form for execution than pure strings), but not executed until later.  But that parsing doesn't do anything to your `User` object.  That only happens when the constructor actually runs.

Comment: So you don't know where exactly in memory interpreter store constructor function code. I'm fully understand how C compilers works. And I’m understand how CLR works and how it uses lazy-compiling for class methods.  So I just what see the whole picture about js (about it memory model). I guess I should read V8 engine to get all thing clear about js memory issues.

Comment: @YuryPetrankov - So now you're asking where javascript stores code that it has parsed?  That is entirely implementation specific and platform specific and not related to the function or operation of the javascript.  What kind of answer are you looking for?  Do you want me to tell you that the code for your function is stored at address 0xB04563AFF9 in memory?  Now I don't understand what you're asking at all.  Sorry, I tried to answer the literal question that you asked (and think I've done that).  If I have not answered the actual question you have, then you will need to clarify.

Comment: @YuryPetrankov - I added a bit more to the end of my answer on when Function objects like your constructor are created.

Comment: The last paragraph is exactly what I wanted to read. Thus, JavaScript's interpreter principles of “compiling” methods very similar to the CLR. Thank you for your explanation.